# Upgraded my mac OS and now the vim colors are different. Is there an easy way for me to change the default syntax?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I upgraded my mac to Catalina and now the vim syntax looks all off to me.  I am sure that strings used to be red, and I think that `def` used to be turquoise and `import` was pink. Is there a simple way for me to change the default syntax coloring so that strings are displayed in red text?

[image]

For reference, here is my `.vimrc` file:

```
:map <S-s><S-s> :w<CR> 
set undofile
set undodir=/Users/kilojoules/.vim/

syntax on
execute pathogen#infect()

autocmd BufReadPost *
     \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
     \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
     \ endif
set undofile                " Save undo's after file closes
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undo " where to save undo histories
```

Comment: It's quite possible the background detection improved (or catalina's terminal better signaled its background) and so the default colorscheme went from behaving like `:set bg=light` to `:set bg=dark`. You could possibly even test if that's the case by setting the background and seeing what happens.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble This was exactly the issue thanks for pointing that out

Comment: please add an answer if you have one that solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely understand your problem. The issue is that the new system is better at detecting the background as being dark. Simply add

```
set bg=light
```

to your `.vimrc` file my friend. That should restore your color scheme to the one you know and love.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a colorscheme and set it in your ~/.vimrc

`colorscheme <colorscheme_name>`